# Call a function every time a new comment is inserted/deleted inside a Word document, using Javascript API for Office Add-Ins

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

An Add-In that I'm creating needs to keep track of all the comments that currently exists in the document.

To do so, I'd like to refrain from having to constantly poll the Word application after a certain time for its data, or also refrain from having to use `Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged` to call the function every time anything changes, because it would be too costly.

Is there any other way that I can know when a comment has been inserted/deleted inside a document?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the COM nor the JS APIs provide an event for this.

With the COM APIs it would be possible to "trap" the insertion by re-purposing the Ribbon controls using Ribbon XML. (VBA can even link into the internal command.) Unfortunately, access to built-in Ribbon controls is not provided by the JS API "commands".

So currently the only possibility besides the event you mention would be to provide your own tools and request the user work with those.

Comment: I see. Making something along the lines of a "custom comment section" was one of our alternatives, but definitely wasn't our preferred choice, as we would be telling our users to discard Word's fully functional commenting features. If I may ask, do you know if Word will eventually integrate Comments natively into their Add-In API and when? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't a clue, I'm afraid - I'm not from Microsoft... I find only one entry on UserVoice and that's pretty old: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13496982-create-word-comments-via-office-api. You might want to enter a new one that's more detailed about what and why it would be useful. In general terms, the Word API team implements features that are available on all platforms, with Word On-line usually setting the limit (fewer features). As Comments was available very early on there I'd think it would be something they'd consider...

Answer (score 1):

Base on my research, i can't find a better way to do that. `Document.SelectionChanged event` is the only method that i found. For more information, please review the following link: [Document.SelectionChanged event](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.selectionchanged.event)

Comment: your link is dead